# How to return an array of unknown size in C

Tags: c, arrays

I want to write a small C program which asks the user for a number input `length_input` and then prints out the first `length_input` characters of some fixed string `string_input`.

Now, this code doesn’t work. It compiles fine, but it always prints an empty line instead of `"AB"` for instance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* take (char* string, int length) {

    char* local_string = malloc(length);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        local_string[i] = string[i]; 
    }

    return local_string;
}

int main (int arg, char** args) {

    char* string_input;
    char* string_output;
    int length_input;

    printf("> ");
    scanf("%s", &length_input);

    string_input = "ABCDEFG";
    string_output = malloc(length_input);
    string_output = take(string_input, length_input);

    printf(string_output);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I assume that is because I return a local variable in `take`, no? I’ve also read that declaring the pointer `local_string` as static variable would help. I understand that its allocated size would then have to be known at compile time, which would render the program pointless.

*The thing is*: The call of `take` should *not* change any local variables of the `main` procedure, or to be more precise: It should change nothing that is defined by the `main` procedure – be it on the stack or on the heap. So I need to return a new pointer to a new address in the heap, not change the values at an existing one. (*Why*? It’s an experiment.)

Is it possible to do what I want? If so, how?

Comment: This `scanf("%s", &length_input);` should make the compiler warn you. Take warnings serious.

Comment: @alk But I didn’t get any warning? I compiled with `gcc -o output program.c` using `gcc (Debian 5.2.1-23) 5.2.1 20151028`. No warnings.

Comment: Your `take` function doesn't null-terminate the string. allocate `length + 1` bytes and make `local_string[length] = '\0'`

Comment: Also don't use user input as format string. What if the user enters `"%d%d%s"`? The format string should be a literal, if possible, so use `printf("%s\n", str)` or maybe just `puts(str)`.

Comment: Do you suggest to not use `scanf`? I never print out user output, as `string_output` is always created from `string_input` (which is statically `"ABCDEFG"`).

Comment: for gcc use `-std=c11 -pedantic` at least; also `-Wall` gives some more useful warnings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First consider what this does [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf)

```
scanf("%s", &length_input);
```

It takes the input text and converts it to a string (%s) (what it already is) then stores it in &length_input (the address of an integer).  Probably not what you want.

Note: length_input will probably still be '0' (its initial value)

It then allocates no memory (malloc(0)); but, since most mallocs have a minimum alloc size, you did get something.

It next calls 'take' which runs the loop once to get the first entry in the array ('AB') and stores that in the lucky buffer.

Then you didn't free what you malloced; so, you probably leaked memory.

You have a few things to fix; but, it did what you told it to.

Comment: Yes! A former version of the program asked for a string and I didn’t change the `%s` to `%i`. Now I changed it and it now works.

Answer (score 1):

Your `take` function is ok. However they way you invoking it is not ok. You should be doing:

```
string_input = "ABCDEFG";
string_output = take(string_input, length_input);
```

Otherwise you end up with a memory leak.